# Pyspark: How to compare two Timestamps to show most recently updated records in dataframe or table?

Tags: python, sql, database, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a script for a daily incremental load process using Pyspark and a Hive table which has already been initially loaded with data. Each morning a job will run the script against that table.

I've been try to use PySpark to create a timestamp filter that will compare two timestamps, `mod_date_ts` and `max(mod_date_ts)` to show updated records that were added since the last load and save the result to the dataframe or another dataframe.

I've tried the following syntax:

```
    dw_mod_ts = base_df.select('dw_mod_ts')
    max_dw_load_ts = base_df.select(max_('dw_mod_ts'))

    inc_df = inc_df.filter(dw_mod_ts >= max_dw_load_ts)
```

But I keep getting type errors and syntax errors stating that a dataframe cannot be compared to str`even though I've casted both variables and columns as`TimestampType`.

```
    inc_df = inc_df.filter(inc_df("dw_mod_ts").cast(DataTypes.DateType) >= max_('dw_mod_ts').cast(DataTypes.DateType))
```

Also, I keep getting an error stating the `>=` operator cannot be used within the current syntax as well.

I don't have much experience working with Pyspark, so any help or suggestions is appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the comparison is in string form. First build the `max_dw_load_ts`  variable, and then pass its value to `filter` to get the final result.

```
max_dw_mod_ts = df.groupBy().agg(F.max('dw_mod_ts')).collect()[0][0]
df = df.filter(f'dw_mod_ts >= "{max_dw_mod_ts}"')
df.show()
```